# clearcase option for view movement from one host path to another

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I have created a clearcase dynamic view for my development by name "view1". I have mistakenly selected the view storage location as a local PC in my network, that was made sharable by the PC owner. I was suppose to select the view storage location to be a server.

Now, the issue is that I have done lot of development with the view that I have created and have plenty of view DO's and view private files in it.

So I'm ruling out the option of deleting the view from the PC local storage (host path) and then creating another view in the server with the same config spec.

Please, let me know if there is any method of editing the view properties (or doing something else) by which I could be able to move the view to the server (with all the DO's and view private files retained)

Thanks in advance,
Rahamath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No official method exist to "move" a view, especially a dynamic one (meaning DO and private files are stored in the view storage)

In theory, you can unregister/register your view with a new path (`cleartool register -view`), but the hostname being different, cleartool won't complete the operation.

On Unix, you could have tried moving the storage to another host, and set an [`alternate_hostname` file](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21220772), but it is [not supported on Windows](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=727&uid=swg21321607).